# Gray "Dust" On Pink Insulation in Attic

Tags: insulation, attic, mold, dust

I was looking in my attic today for the first time; it's been on my list to check up there to make sure nothing looks off (i.e. no water damage, the roof isn't falling apart, etc).

One thing I noticed was there's some gray coloring in my pink insulation up there:
[image: Attic 1]
[image: Attic 2]
[image: Attic 3]
[image: Attic 4]

Normally I'd just assume this is dust settling in the attic which I never go up in, but after Googling a bit it apparently could be mold. I'd like to get a second opinion to determine if it's mold growing in the pink insulation or if it's just dust settling on top.

If the images I've posted do not provide the proper insight please feel free to comment to let me know and I can provide more specific pictures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been in no less than 300 attics and every one of then has had dust, grey dust, in them. Your attic has soffits installed to vent the attic. You also have vent pipes going through the roof to vent caps that allow some backdraft into the attic. If you've ever had your roof redone, stuff will be knocked down. Mold needs a fare amount of moisture and most of the attics I've been in just don't have it.

If this is going to keep you up at night, you can always have a piece of the insulation tested.

Comment: Definitely not losing sleep over it; I was mostly hoping for an answer exactly like this. I haven't been in many attics before (2, to be exact) I wasn't sure if this was normal, which it sounds like it is. I'll give it a bit more time before I accept your answer, but I don't doubt you're correct.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any darkening on the braces, rafters, or underside of the roof deck, as I would expect if you had that much mold.  It looks like plain dust to me.